# Build lumen in docker

Tags: laravel, docker, lumen

I have a problem when I build lumen on docker, but when the build process is finished there is an error like this :

E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-
dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr     && docker-php-ext-install gd mbstring pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql zip' returned a non-zero code: 100

So the build process fails.
Has anyone ever had a case like me? I hope someone can provide a solution.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile, please?

Comment: this is config my dockerfile :

FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd mbstring pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql zip

Answer (score 3):

Try `libpng-dev` instead of `libpng12-dev`, that one is deprecated and has been removed

Answer (score 0):

try this in your Dockerfile

```
RUN apk add --no-cache php \
    php7-common \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-zip \
    php7-phar \
    php7-iconv \
    php7-cli \
    php7-curl \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-fileinfo \
    php7-json \
    php7-xml \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    php7-simplexml \
    php7-dom \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-pdo_pgsql \
    php7-pdo_sqlite \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-pecl-redis \
    nginx supervisor curl
```

Comment: use only the dependencies you need, not all of them